# How to do Spring Lookup Method Injection with Annotations?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-annotations

Is there any way to use Lookup Method Injection using annotations?

Given the following class:

```
@Service
public abstract class A {


    protected abstract createB();

}
```

In order to get it to work I have to declare in spring applicationContext.xml the following:

```
<bean id="b" class="com.xyz.B">
</bean>

<bean id="a" class="com.xyz.A">
    <lookup-method name="createB" bean="b"/>
</bean>
```

Even though I am using `<context:component-scan base>` I have to declare it also in the XML. Not a good approach I think.

How to do it with annotations?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is possible to use `javax.inject.Provider`. All thanks go to [Phil Webb](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5192?focusedCommentId=86051&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-86051).

```
public class MySingleton {

  @Autowired
  private Provider<MyPrototype> myPrototype;

  public void operation() {
    MyPrototype instance = myPrototype.get();
    // do something with the instance
  }

}
```

Comment: Please also note the answer about @Lookup below - it's possible with Spring 4.1 ot later to use the annotation. Even though I think the Provider is much cleaner and less confusing while reading the code.

Answer (score 17):

It is also possible with `org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory` if you want to keep up with Spring API

```
public class MySingleton {

  @Autowired
  private ObjectFactory<MyPrototype> myPrototypeFactory;

  public void operation() {
    MyPrototype instance = myPrototypeFactory.getObject();
    // do something with the instance
  }
}
```

you can read more in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectFactory.html).

Answer (score 13):

It is implemented only with Spring >= 4.1 See the [ticket](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5192).

Comment: In Spring Framework 4.1 it is available as the \@Lookup annotation. See @Danny-Dan's answer.

Comment: Thanks, udpated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 10):

Finally introduced as  [@Lookup](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Lookup.html) annotation. Here is [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26034662/2420028) on how to use it.

Comment: The @Lookup annotation requires Spring 4.1 or later