# Request scoped field in a Singleton bean

Tags: java, spring, annotations, singleton

I know it's possible to inject a request scoped bean into a singleton bean in Spring so I know what I'm trying to do will work, I'm just wondering if there is a way to express it more concisely without so many extra unnecessary class definitions. I'm new to Spring annotations so maybe there's an annotation I don't know about.

I have an abstract class that will be extended maybe 100 times in my application as different singleton spring beans. Take this class definition for an example:

```
/** The abstract class with a field that needs to be request-specific **/
public abstract class AbstractSingletonBean {

    private SampleState state;
    public SampleState getState() { return state; }
    public void setState(SampleState state) { this.state = state; }

    // Other fields that are just singleton here
}
```

And an example of what one of the bean definitions might look like:

```
@Component
public class SampleSingletonBean extends AbstractSingletonBean {

    @Resource(name="sampleState")
    public void setState(SampleState state) { super.setState(state); }
}
```

Now of course we need a bean called `sampleState`. So I have to create two classes: a base class to define the fields in `SampleState` and then a request-scoped bean definition. This is because each extension of `AbstractSingletonBean` will need it's own request-scoped instance of the state field.

Here might be the base class:

```
public class SampleState {
    private String fieldOne;
    public String getFieldOne() { return fieldOne }
    public void setFieldOne() { this.fieldOne = fieldOne }
}
```

And here is this silly bean definition:

```
@Component ("sampleState")
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SampleStateBean extends SampleState {}
```

The thing that bothers me is that if I have 100 extensions of `AbstractSingletonBean`, I'll need 100 extensions of `SampleStateBean` with just boilerplate code to make it request-scoped. Is there a way to just override `setState()` in the extensions of `AbstractSingletonBean` and indicate to spring that it should create a new request scoped bean on the fly and inject it here?  So my `SampleSingletonBean` could look like this:

```
@Component
public class SampleSingletonBean extends AbstractSingletonBean {

    @Resource
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public void setState(SampleState state) { super.setState(state); }
}
```

Of course this doesn't work because `@Resource` needs to refer to a bean that already exists. Is there another annotation to accomplish this without creating a new class for every `SampleState` bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like this was available out of the box so I created an annotation I call @AnonymousRequest that I put on the field I want, and a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor to do the work of creating the bean. It basically goes like this:

```
for each bean in the BeanFactory
  if bean class has AnonymousRequest annotation
    create request scoped bean from field class
    create singleton bean to be request scoped bean wrapper
    set the annotated property value to the singleton wrapper
```

This took a lot of work to figure out how Spring registers request scoped beans. You create the bean definition you want as a request scoped bean. Then you create a singleton bean of type RootBeanDefinition that acts as a wrapper to the request scope bean and set a property on the wrapper called "targetBeanName" to whatever you named the request scoped bean ("scopedTarget." + the singleton bean name by convention).

So this could probably be improved by someone who actually knows this stuff but here's what I came up with:

```
  public void createRequestBeanFromSetterMethod(String containingBeanName, BeanDefinition containingBean, Method method, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry)
  {
    String fieldName = ReflectionUtil.getFieldNameFromSetter(method.getName());
    String singletonBeanName = containingBeanName+"_"+fieldName;
    String requestBeanName = "scopedTarget."+singletonBeanName;

    BeanDefinition requestBean = createAnonymousRequestBean(ReflectionUtil.getFieldTypeFromSetter(method), containingBean);

    RootBeanDefinition singletonBean = new RootBeanDefinition();
    singletonBean.setBeanClass(ScopedProxyFactoryBean.class);
    singletonBean.getPropertyValues().addPropertyValue("targetBeanName", requestBeanName);

    registry.registerBeanDefinition(singletonBeanName, singletonBean);
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(requestBeanName, requestBean);

    beanDefinition.getPropertyValues().addPropertyValue(fieldName, new RuntimeBeanReference(singletonBeanName));

  }

  private BeanDefinition createAnonymousRequestBean(Class<?> beanType, BeanDefinition parentBean)
  {
    BeanDefinition newBean = null;
    if (parentBean != null)
    {
      newBean = new GenericBeanDefinition(parentBean);
    }
    else
    {
      newBean = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    }

    if (beanType != null)
    {
      newBean.setBeanClassName(beanType.getName());
    }

    newBean.setScope("request");
    newBean.setAutowireCandidate(false);

    // This would have come from the Proxy annotation...could add support for different values
    String proxyValue = "org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AutoProxyUtils.preserveTargetClass";
    BeanMetadataAttribute attr = new BeanMetadataAttribute(proxyValue, true);
    newBean.setAttribute(proxyValue, attr);

    return newBean;
  }
```

It seems to work! I effectively have now a request scoped bean created just before the context initialization that is localized to this one containing bean. It's a request-scoped property, more or less.

Answer (score 1):

Spring can inject into abstract classes too. So you can move the injection of the `SampleState` to the abstract class, if each `AbstractSingletonBean` descendant needs just a `SampleState` (as in your example).

Comment: Yeah but each AbstractSingletonBean instance needs its own SampleState instance, not a reference to the same SampleState request scoped bean everywhere.

Comment: With a request scoped bean, a different instance of `SampleState` bean will be created and injected for every request.

Comment: I would need a different instance of SampleState for every request and every instance of AbstractSingletonBean. So in one request if I'm working with 10 beans that extend from AbstractSingletonBean, that request would need 10 different instances of SampleState.

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining single SampleState request scope bean and then use spring's lookup method to inject this bean wherever you want to.That's works just fine with prototype-scope beans. Fingers crosses it would work with request scope as well.

AFAIK, there is no annotation support for lookup method as of now, so either use it's xml vis-a-vis
or have a look at javax.inject.Provider [relevant question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891997/how-to-do-spring-lookup-method-injection-with-annotations)

Comment: I'm sure each injection would end up getting a reference to the same bean. Prototype beans work like that because by definition each injection is a new reference.