# How to use spring @Lookup annotation?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I need to get prototype class from singleton. I found that method injection is the way to go, but I don't really know how to use spring @Lookup annotation.

I'm new to dependency-injection, and I chose to go with annotation configuration, so I would like to continue in that direction.

I found out that @Lookup annotation was added only recently (https://spring.io/blog/2014/09/04/spring-framework-4-1-ga-is-here), but I cannot find anywhere how to use it.

So, here is simplified example

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
public class ApplicationConfiguration implements ApplicationConfigurationInterface {

  @Bean
  public MyClass1 myClass1() {
    return new ContentHolderTabPaneController();
  }

  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public MyClass2 myClass2() {
    return new SidebarQuickMenuController();
  }
}
```

And here is class example:

```
public class MyClass1 {
  doSomething() {
    myClass2();
  }

  //I want this method to return MyClass2 prototype
  public MyClass2 myClass2(){
  }
}
```

How do I do that with @Lookup annotation?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Before applying `@Lookup` annotation to your `public MyClass2 myClass2()` method, read this in [@Lookup's Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Lookup.html):

> the container will generate runtime subclasses of the method's containing class via CGLIB, which is why such lookup methods can only work on beans that the container instantiates through regular constructors (i.e. **lookup methods cannot get replaced on beans returned from factory methods** where we can't dynamically provide a subclass for them).

So remove the following factory method style bean declaration from `ApplicationConfiguration`:

```
  @Bean
  public MyClass1 myClass1() {
    return new ContentHolderTabPaneController();
  }
```

and add `@Component` annotation to let Spring instantiate the bean (also add the `@Lookup` annotation to the method):

```
@Component
public class MyClass1 {
  doSomething() {
    myClass2();
  }

  //I want this method to return MyClass2 prototype
  @Lookup
  public MyClass2 myClass2(){
    return null; // This implementation will be overridden by dynamically generated subclass
  }
}
```

Now get `myClass1` bean out of context, and its `myClass2` method should have been replaced/overridden to get a new prototype bean each time.

---

*Update*:

## Using factory method declaration

It's not hard to implement the `@Lookup` annotated method (the "lookup method"). Without `@Lookup` and keeping your configuration class unchanged, now `MyClass1` looks like (in fact Spring generates a similar implementation in a subclass if `@Lookup` were used):

```
public class MyClass1 {
  doSomething() {
    myClass2();
  }

  //I want this method to return MyClass2 prototype
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
  public MyClass2 myClass2() {
      return applicationContext.getBean(MyClass2.class);
  }
}
```

Spring injects the `ApplicationContext` for you.

Comment: Thank you.

And is there a way to use that MyClass1 Bean in a factory style bean declaration as dependency?

Comment: Then we implement our own lookup method - luckily it's very easy. See my update to the answer.

Comment: But isn't that sort of defeating purpose of DI, because Bean actually has to be aware of DI container?

Comment: Yes, so method injection is [prefereed](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection). I don't see an easy way of using factory method bean declaration with method injection.

Comment: applicationContext.getBean(MyClass2.class) == @Lookup ?

Comment: To save the IoC pattern, use the provider injection (with javax.inject.Provider). see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16714945/1444061

Comment: to use the next point: return applicationContext.getBean(MyClass2.class);
its really the bad code because you inject the infrustructure component into the business logic

Answer (score 7):

If you are not on Spring 4.1 you can use the provider injection instead:

```
public class MyClass1 {
  @Autowired
  private Provider<MyClass2> myClass2Provider;

  doSomething() {
    MyClass2 myClass2 = myClass2();
    myClass2.fooBar()
  }

  public MyClass2 myClass2(){
    return myClass2Provider.get();
  }
}
```

This is DI, IoC, avoids abstract classes and xml definitions for lookup methods.

Comment: `javax.inject.Provider` to be precise

Comment: This worked great in my unit tests. I couldn't get @Lookup to work

Comment: Is there a thing along those lines that would allow passing initial arguments for the bean?

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can declare myClass2 bean with TARGET_CLASS proxyMode.

```
  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  public MyClass2 myClass2() {
    return new SidebarQuickMenuController();
  }
```