# Spring @Bean with @Lookup method

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations

I've implemented a Spring bean utilizing the @Lookup annotation. (This thread was helpful: [How to use spring @Lookup annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028341/how-to-use-spring-lookup-annotation))

I've subsequently noticed a strange behavior that I'm not sure is by design or my own misunderstanding. Spring will implement a @Lookup method in a ComponentScan-ed bean annotated with @Service, @Component, etc. but will not implement such a method in a @Bean defined in a @Configuration class (Application.java).

This isn't a big problem, as I can remove the @Bean definition from the configuration and instead annotate its class directly; but I'm wondering whether this behavior is documented somewhere, or am I implementing it incorrectly?

```
@Bean
public Service getService() {
    // ServiceImpl has a @Lookup method,
    // but Spring does not implement it unless the class itself is annotated.
    return new ServiceImpl();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact this behavior *is* a limitation of the `@Lookup` annotation. The latest version of Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Lookup.html) describes the caveat more explicitly than it did back in version 4.1.

> ...please remember that lookup methods won't work on beans returned from `@Bean` methods in configuration classes;

In general, objects returned from `@Bean` methods *do* have their annotations processed; `@Lookup` is an exception to the typical behavior.