# why does lookup method only works on component class but not on a bean called one?

Tags: spring, configuration, lookup

So im trying to understand why a @Bean created object that contains a @LookUp doesnt work, but works with a @Component one. Here [one user says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239965/spring-bean-with-lookup-method) that annotations on @bean called classes will not be processed, but i just tried a class that contains an @Autowired field and this class was instantiated with @Bean in the @Configuration class and it worked.

Comment: The last sentence in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Lookup.html) also states that it will not work.

Comment: But i assume that some annotations do work in a class when called with @bean.