# Spring Prototype-Bean Provider without @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

I have a prototype Bean which is instantiated by singleton bean with a `Provider`:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class MyPrototype {}

@Component
class MySingleton {
    @Autowired
    javax.inject.Provider<MyPrototype> prototypeFactory;
}
```

This works fine, but our company rules state that `@Autowired` is not allowed; the common pattern is `@Resource(SingletonBeanClass.BEAN_ID)`.

Is it possible to annotate the `Provider` this way so the Spring lookup can create it?

I'm aware I can add a factory method with `@Lookup`, or a singleton factory bean, but I prefer the `Provider`.

EDIT:
I didn't get it to work this way and in the end had to edit `spring.xml`; see below for details.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `@Autowired` is not allowed?

Comment: @araknoid I think they want direct control over what class is instantiated... doesn't make much sense to me, but I'm not in the position to argue this.

Comment: Is @Inject (from javax.inject) allowed?

Comment: You can configure it via XML if you have an XML configuration file for bean injections

Comment: @MystyxMac At least the automatic QA check doesn't complain, trying to get away with this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have an XML configuration file, you can configure it via XML in the following way:

```
<bean id="myPrototype" class="some.package.MyPrototype" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="mySingleton" class="some.package.MySingleton">
    <lookup-method name="getPrototypeFactory" bean="myPrototype "/>
</bean>
```

In this way, you have to access to the myPrototype with the `getPrototypeFactory()` and not directly to the property. You can even remove the annotations on those 2 classes.

For any extra details, you can look at the following blog post [Injecting a prototype bean into a singleton bean](https://prasanthnath.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/injecting-a-prototype-bean-into-a-singleton-bean/)

Comment: It's what I ended up doing; I just wrote an answer myself because it was a bit more complicated. Setting yours to "answered" though.

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed, you can't use `ref` or the prototype bean will be created only once for the singleton, but I had to instantiate it several times during the singletons lifetime.

Comment: @daniu Corrected my answer. Wrong configuration pasted and added a little extra details.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, if someone comes across this via Google:

I ended up needing to declare it in the `spring.xml`. I tried `@Lookup`, but even that didn't work due to the prototype-bean referencing yet another prototype-bean.

This is how it was [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028341/how-to-use-spring-lookup-annotation),
**but it does not work:**

```
@Component("proto1")
@Scope("prototype")
class MyPrototypeBean1 {
    @Lookup(value="proto2")
    protected MyPrototypeBean2 createBean2() { return null; }
}

@Component("proto2")
@Scope("prototype")
class MyPrototypeBean2 {
}

@Component("singleton")
class MySingleton {
    @Lookup(value="proto1")
    protected MyPrototypeBean1 createBean1() { return null; }
}
```

This results in the error message "Cannot apply @Lookup to beans without corresponding bean definition" when trying to create "innerBean...".

I assume it is due to "lookup methods cannot get replaced on beans returned from factory methods where we can't dynamically provide a subclass for them" as is quoted in the link above.

So what I ended up doing in the `spring.xml`:

```
<bean name="proto2" class="my.package.PrototypeBean2" />
<bean name="proto1" class="my.package.PrototypeBean1" >
    <lookup-method name="createBean2" bean="proto2" />
</bean>
<bean name="singleton" class="my.package.SingletonBean" >
    <lookup-method name="createBean1" bean="proto1" />
</bean>
```

And this works.

For the unit tests, I had to subclass the respective classes:

```
class SingletonUnitTest {
    @Mock
    MyPrototypeBean1 bean1;
    @InjectMocks
    DummySingleton sut;

    @Before public void setBean1() {
        sut.bean = bean1;
    }

    static class DummySingletonBean extends MySingeton {
        MyPrototypeBean1 bean;
        protected MyPrototypeBean1 createBean1() {
            return bean;
        }
    }
}
```