# How to create a factory-method with arguments?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, factory-method, spring-ioc

Could you please help me to get rid of `ApplicationContext`?

I have a factory so that all book instances are spring-beans.
I think it's a good decision to make all beans spring-beans.

```
@Component
public class BookFactoryImpl implements BookFactory {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public BookFactoryImpl(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Book createBook(String name) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(Book.class, name);
    }

}
```

Here is a configuration class with a `@Bean`method that is used to instantiate a new instance of `Book` class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"factory"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Lazy
    public Book book(String name) {
        return Book.builder().name(name).build();
    }

}
```

Here is my `Book` entity class:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Builder
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private String name;

}
```

I have more one idea - to annotate `BookFactoryImpl` with `@Configuration` and move `@Bean` method in it but in this case, my factory will be turned into `@Configuration` class with the broken lifecycle.

What do you think, what is the best way to implement a factory and how to reduce external dependencies like `ApplicationContext`?

Or maybe it's nice to make all factories as `@Configuration` classes with `@Bean` methods, how do you think?

Comment: How `Book` instances are used? what is calling `BookFactory.createBook()`?

Comment: Assume that psvm() invokes it. It doesn’t matter, simply client code

Comment: what is the purpose of creating new Book instances? I guess you want to persist them in the db? Are they used by a repository?

Comment: yep, for instance, I can persist them - they're entities

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a good idea to make every single class in your application managed by Spring.

JPA entities usually should be instantiated by your code inside Spring managed beans.

Comment: Could you explain thoroughly? Do you mean just to call builder on Book class in a client code? What if I want init-method on it?

Comment: In the snippet you have provided Builder also does not make sense. If your entity has 1 or 2 attributes a builder is an over-engineering. So just do `new Book().setName(name);`. Read also about the advantages of having an immutable model.

Comment: I would like to have immutable objects where it's possible. If I have mutable data I could simply use @Lookup method and then setter

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following approach:

Define the singleton bean that will contain a dependency on factory:

```
    public class MyService {
     private final Provider<Book> bookFactory;

     public MyService(Provider<Book> bookFactory) {
         this.bookFactory = bookFactory;
     } 
     public void doSomething() {
        Book book = bookFactory.get();
        book.setNumberOfReaders(numOfReaders); // this is a drawback, book is mutable, if we want to set runtime params (like numberOfReaders)
         ....
      }
    }
```

Now Define a prototype for book bean:

```
@Configuration 
public class MyConfiguration {

   @Bean
   @Scope("prototype")
   public Book book(...) {
      return new Book(...);
   }

   @Bean // scope singleton by default
   public MyService myService(Provider<Book> bookFactory) {
       return new MyService(bookFactory);
   }
}
```

Notice, Provider is of type "javax.inject.Provider", in order to use id, import (for example in maven):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring can handle this since 4.x ( I guess 4.1) without any additional configuration

Of course, this approach eliminates that need to inject application context to the factory and in general to maintain a factory

One drawback is that it doesn't allow building the object with arguments, these arguments have to be specified in runtime.

There is also another approach, a runtime generation of sub-class in conjunction with `@Lookup` annotation, its described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028341/how-to-use-spring-lookup-annotation) but IMO Provider approach is better.

Comment: Seems easier to make a Lookup method and call it and use setter